# conditional with multiples operations inside

Tags: notation, python

I have a python script and I want to write them mathematically, the conditional is:

```
if a>b:
  a=5
  b=3
elif a<b:
  a=0
  b=5
else:
  a=2
  b=0
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can I write?

$$
a=
\begin{cases}
5,b=3 &if \: a>b\\
0,b=5 &if \: a<b\\
2,b=0 &otherwise\\
\end{cases}
$$